# Input-Scan Barcode PHP

Tags: php, get, barcode-scanner

i have this form

> form_insert.php

```
<form action="stock_insert.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="barcode" placeholder="Εισαγωγή BarCode"> <br>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Όνομα"> <br>
        <input type="text" name="size" placeholder="Μέγεθος"> <br>
        <input type="text" name="style" placeholder="Στυλ"> <br>
        <input type="text" name="color" placeholder="Χρώμα">  <br>
        <input type="text" name="mark" placeholder="Μάρκα"> <br>
        <input type="text" name="value" placeholder="Ποσότητα">  <br>
        <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Τιμή"> <br>
        <select name="kind">
            <option >Σταθερά</option>
            <option >Φθινόπωρο</option>
            <option >Χειμώνας</option>
            <option >Άνοιξη</option>
            <option >Καλοκαίρι</option>
        </select> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="Αποθήκευση"  placeholder="Αποθήκευση">
</form>
```

I want to insert in my database the inputs.

> stock_insert.php

```
<?php
include_once  'database_connection.php';

$barcode = $_GET['barcode'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$size = $_GET['size'];
$style = $_GET['style'];
$color = $_GET['color'];
$mark = $_GET['mark'];
$kind = $_GET['kind'];
$value = $_GET['value'];
$price =$_GET['price'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `stock`(`barcode`, `name`, `size`,  `style`, `color`, `mark`, `kind`, `value` , price) VALUES ('$barcode','$name','$size','$style','$color','$mark' ,'$kind','$value', $price);";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header('Location: form_insert.php?signup=success');
```

But every time , that i'm **scanning**  my Barcode into the input , it automatically refreshes and disappears

What should i do to avoid it ?

Comment: Everytime you scan barcode, it hits enter automatically after that. And you form submit. I think this is the case, pls confirm?

Comment: Don’t let the form submit, and capture the field contents & send them to the server in the background using AJAX instead? (Then you probably want to remove the location header at the end though, and replace that with something that constitutes are more sensible response for that kind of scenario.)

Comment: Read up on SQL injection too - you're wide open at the minute :)

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: "every time , that i'm scanning my Barcode into the input , it automatically refreshes"...you mean instantly, or after you press Submit? it sounds like maybe something is causing the form to submit automatically after you do the scan operation? Do you have any JavaScript in your page? Please clarify the exact circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

**Thanks for the  comments**  guys.  Here is  the  solution.

> AJAX CODE

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#submit").click(function(){
                var barcode =  $("#barcode").val();
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var size = $("#size").val();
                var style  = $("#style").val();
                var color = $("#color").val();
                var mark = $("#mark").val();
                var value  = $("#value").val();
                var price = $("#price").val();
                var kind = $("#kind").val();
                $.post("stock_insert.php", 
                {
                    barcode: barcode ,
                    name: name ,
                    size: size ,
                    style: style ,
                    color: color ,
                    mark: mark ,
                    value: value ,
                    price: price ,
                    kind: kind 
                },function(data,status){
                    alert(status);

                });


           });
        });
    </script>
```

> Inputs

```
<input type="text" id="barcode" name="barcode" placeholder="Εισαγωγή BarCode"> <br>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Όνομα"> <br>
        <input type="text" id="size" name="size" placeholder="Μέγεθος"> <br>
        <input type="text" id="style" name="style" placeholder="Στυλ"> <br>
        <input type="text" id="color" name="color" placeholder="Χρώμα">  <br>
        <input type="text" id="mark" name="mark" placeholder="Μάρκα"> <br>
        <input type="text" id="value" name="value" placeholder="Ποσότητα">  <br>
        <input type="text" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Τιμή"> <br>
        <select id="kind" name="kind">
            <option >Σταθερά</option>
            <option >Φθινόπωρο</option>
            <option >Χειμώνας</option>
            <option >Άνοιξη</option>
            <option >Καλοκαίρι</option>
        </select> <br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Αποθήκευση"  placeholder="Αποθήκευση">
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ will save you a lot of lines of code here... (also, it's a good idea to handle the "submit" event of the form, rather than the "click" event of the button)